# Callback with NPM Python Shell for Electron

Tags: javascript, python, npm, callback

So this is my code, I am using python sheel to execute a python script that reads RFID Tags. The python script is working fine, but my problem is that I want to console.log("testing") after the python script is executed (when I put the tag over the RFID reader), instead it's console logging "testing" first and then executing the python script. Is there any way I solve this problem, callback or something?

```
function getDadosPulseira(){
    var {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
    var path = require('path')

    var options = {
        scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, '../_engine/')//,
    }

    var readrfid = new PythonShell('readtag.py', options)

    readrfid.on("message", function(message) {
        swal({
            title: "Pulseira!",
            text: message,
            icon: "success",
            timer: 3000
        });
        console.log(message);
    })

    console.log("testing");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getDadosPulseira() {
            var {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
            var path = require('path')

            var options = {
              scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, '../_engine/')//,
            }

            var readrfid = new PythonShell('readtag.py', options)

            readrfid.on("message", function(message) {
              swal({
                title: "Pulseira!",
                text: message,
                icon: "success",
                timer: 3000
             });
             console.log(message);
         })
         readrfid.end(function (err) { 
          console.log("testing"); 
         });
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it's still printing "testing" and then the python script is executed. I want the python script to execute and then "testing" is printed. I am very noob at javascript but is there any way to stop the program until I put the tag over the RFID reader?

Comment: You should write the console.log("testing"); into this function 
      `readrfid.end(function (err) {
        console.log("testing");
        });`                                                                                                           @GonçaloOliveira

Comment: Also, do you know how to make a loop so that the python script would be always being executed so that I could put the Tag over the rfid reader and then do it over again...? I am trying to do a while loop but my program stops and doesn't let me do anything

Comment: Do I have to do It on the python side or on the javascript?

Comment: I think this reason may be caused by promise function, you can delete it and put again do while loop in js part because promise function returns one thing and your program stops.

Comment: i will edit code part, tell me if did not work @GonçaloOliveira

Comment: I was able to solve by adding a function that sleeps for 3 seconds in the while loop